# What are some uses for an O2/N2 mixture that is more N2-rich than air?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

What are some uses for an $\ce{O2}$/$\ce{N2}$ mixture that is more $\ce{N2}$-rich than air?
I need help with this, my professor did not do a good job explaining it, and I can't find a source to read about it.

Comment: Do they use it in scuba diving tanks?

Comment: They kinda do, only the other way around: they use oxygen-enriched mixture (before resorting to $\ce{He}$, but that's another story).

Comment: Nitrogen enriched air is used as an [inerting gas in fuel tanks, (WARNING:  pdf)](https://www.fire.tc.faa.gov/pdf/01-6.pdf), where the oxygen content is low enough that you don't get flammability.

Comment: Nitrogen is an inert gas. It does not react very easily. Conversely, oxygen is highly reactive. If there were more O2 than N2 we may expect to age more quickly, and also insects would be GIGANTIC. N2 is also responsible for forming NH3 with H2 in small traces. The Miller-Urey experiment proved that amino acids can form with sufficient energy in the presence H2, H2O, CH4, and NH3.

Answer (score 2):

Some laboratories do use, and possibly some processes use "synthetic air", which contains 5% oxygen. This is to carry out oxidation reactions or processes but reduces the amount of excess oxygen to prevent unwanted combustion e.g. if flammable solvents are also being used. Many university research labs will use this if carrying out pressurised reactions.

Answer (score 2):

I personally used custom $\ce{O2}$/$\ce{N2}$ mixtures in my Ph.D. work, both higher and lower in $\ce{N2}$ than air.  The application dealt with precisely controlled delivery of [nitric oxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitric_oxide) $\left(\ce{NO}\right)$ to aqueous solutions, to study how changing the $\ce{NO}$ concentration affects cell damage, cancer formation, etc.  In much of the body, the $\ce{O2}$ concentration is reduced below the air-equilibrated value, so it was important to design the system such that tests could be run with similar, lower-than-ambient $\ce{O2}$ concentrations.  I thus used nitrogen-enriched mixtures to hold the dissolved oxygen concentration steady at the target values.

For more detail, see my thesis [here](http://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/70107); particularly, Section 2.2.9 (p51) and Section 2.3.3 (pp60-65, including Table 2.3, Figure 2.6, and Figure A.5)

Answer (score 2):

One potential use is in anything to do with fire suppression. Some low oxygen mixtures are breathable while suppressing common burning materials.

This may be a safer way to prevent harm from burning in places like laboratories and server rooms that some of the alternatives (freon fire suppression is dangerous to people, for example). Commercial systems to fill such locations with a low-oxygen atmosphere exist (see [here](http://www.firesuppression.co.uk/hypoxic-air-.aspx)). At oxygen levels below about 15%, things like candles and matches won't burn, but people can still breathe.